# Inline CSS and Mobile CSS Overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with inline css and bootstrap and mobile css. First of all I need to talk about the project. My company creating a MVC project and my role is make an adaptation for mobile devices to this project. It must be really easy because they use bootstrap at all, but the code that I will show above,that you guys can understand what I need to handle with.

```
<div class="row padding-right" style="width: 1055px;">
```

My simple question is, I need to overwrite width:1055px; I know !important width:100% is a horrible solution but I will overwrite this code.

I tried this and it is not working

```
@media (max-width: 568px)
{
    .padding-right
    {
        width:568px !important;     
    }
}
```

I cant not change the row because I am using it in everywhere, I also cannot edit the views at all

I may changing wrong div, but I could not find out. Bootstrap, Inline css, Their own Css file and my mobile css, everything is meshed up, I need to solve this

Comment: `important;` is `!important` `!` is necessary

Comment: I am sorry I didnot copy paste the code, but I tried important with !important, there is no mistake over there but Thank you @Dhaval Marthak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will over-ride inline styles. http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

> @media (max-width: 568px) {
>
> .row.padding-right[style] {
>   width: 568px !important; 
>   }
>
> }

If the site is in a database, then why not remove that inline style, or download the site, do a find and replace.

Comment: because this is a team project and I am only allowed to write my own css style file for mobile, This is the answer that I already know, however this is a horrible solution but there is no other way, thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, !important really annoying to deal with. But the other team should never use inline styles, that's worse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Media Query CSS would over-write the inline css.....in the end,inline-css is the boss always

Still,Try using MQ this way:

```
  @media only screen /* add screen and word "and" */
        and (max-width: 568px)
        {
            /* style here */
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I am doing

Comment: m bad in english...can you rephrase??? are you doing this and getting the problem???